# `keystroke` package doesn't work with polyglossia in TeXLive 2012

Tags: xetex, texlive, polyglossia

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{keystroke}
\begin{document}
\keystroke{Q}
\end{document}
```

Error (when running `xelatex test.tex`):

```
! Package polyglossia Error:
The current roman font does not contain the Cyrillic script!
Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 \keystroke{Q}
```

When I compile with TeXLive 2009, the same file works fine. What is wrong?

Comment: The fact that it "worked" in TeX Live 2009 doesn't say much. Don't load `xltxtra`, but `fontspec` and define as main font one that has support for cyrillic.

Comment: @egreg - I updated the example. It now uses fontspec, defines `Ubuntu` as a new font, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is, unfortunately, not very informative. The `keystroke` package uses, for its drawings, the sans serif font.

In some cases Polyglossia is not able to extract information about the scripts supported by a font, so you have to help it. But first of all, you have to set a sans serif font. Here's the version with Linux Libertine and Biolinum (I don't have Ubuntu):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{keystroke}
\begin{document}
\keystroke{Q}
\end{document}
```

Try with

```
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Ubuntu}
```

and, if the message is still there, add

```
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}[Ligatures=TeX]{Ubuntu}
```